# Django redirect after GET - MEDIA_URL

Tags: django-rest-framework

All work fine for the moment. For example, an url with an image name encoded base64, is redirected correctly :

with GET operation "https://myurl/v1/images/c3VwZXJpbWFnZS5qcGc=/contenu" there is a 302 status code and the navigator send the image with 200 status code with the url "https:myurl/api/mediafiles/superimage.jpg"

This is a part of my urls.py :

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(router_v1.urls)),
    path('myurl/v1/images/<str:nom_image>/contenu', v1.myRedirectView.as_view(), name='image_redirect'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and the correspondig views.py :

```py
class myRedirectView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        nom_image = kwargs['nom_image']
        nom_image = nom_image.encode('utf-8')
        nom_image = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(nom_image).decode()
        url = '/api/mediafiles/' + nom_image
        return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

Now, i would like to find a solution to hide the url (GET) "https:myurl/api/mediafiles/superimage.jpg"
What is the best way ?

- Second redirect (i try but doesn't work)
- Work with my webserver nginx ?
- DjangoRest is not the solution to serve images with API REST ?

Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

update my post, the solution to work in my development environment is to execute the redirection through Nginx :

```
location ~ ^/myurl/v1/images/(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1/api/mediafiles/fastorchidee/$1;
}
```

The regex have to be modified, but it works for the moment !